# Run webpack plugin through angular CLI

Tags: webpack, angular-cli, webpack-plugin

how to run webpack plugin via CLI?
I found something like that, but this is not what I need.
`npx webpack plugin`

Comment: in you angular.json, do you use `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser` in the `architect.build.builder` property?

Comment: Yes, I do......

Comment: great, the answer will be simplier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [custom-webpack builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack)

Configure your custom webpack as a function, the parameter that will be injected at build time is the existing webpack configuration - which is the one angular define.

Like so:

**webpack.config.js**  - (which is defined in angular.json architect.buid.options.customWebpackConfig.path)

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const YourCustomPlugin = require('./YourCustomPlugin');

// Config parameter is Angular default configurations.
module.exports = function(angularConfig) {
    return merge(angularConfig, {
        plugins: [new YourCustomPlugin()],
        ... // other custom webpack configuration
    });
};
```

Worth mentioning there's another solution with [ngx-build-plus](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus)

Comment: At first, if i already have some config in this file I have to add this one level with "plugins"?
Secondly, which command can I use to launch one specific plugin?

Comment: yes, I'll update my answer. Webpack will launch it for you in the hook that you defined inside your plugin

Comment: yes, I know that and it works like that now. I'm wondering if I can somehow run 1 specific plugin without starting the webpack build. For example, something like `webpack plugin my-wp-plugin.js`

Comment: what does your plugin do? If it doesn't need a webpack build then you can run it in node: `node my-wp-plugin`

Comment: if this answered work for you, can you please accept it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me. I created another file that does not depend on webpack in any way and ran it through node cli as a regular js file